# Angular 4 : Component reload behaves differently in production mode and development mode

Tags: angular, production-environment

I encountered very weird behavior between production mode and development mode.

I have a ListComponent that will be server when visitor navigate to /list
in the list page we show a list of items and visitor can click to the item detail.
After navigated to detail page, visitor can click browser back to return to the /list.
I have debugged and find out that, in Development mode when browser back the ListComponent does not init again so its previous state is intact. While in Production mode the browser back make the ListComponent init again

How come Angular having such differences, I can not see much related information when google ?

Comment: I think that can be related to Client State or Angular Routing but I can't find any relevant info.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction?